# Two chemicals A and B are mixed together in a vat (ODE question)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Two chemical species, $A$ and $B$, are mixed together in a vat. $A$ turns into $B$ at a certain rate $k_1$. Meanwhile, the reverse reaction also occurs, with $B$ turning back to $A$ at a different rate $k_2$. If $x_A$ stands for the quantity of species $A$ and $x_B$ stands for the quantity of species $B$, then
>
> $$\begin{aligned}\frac{dx_A}{dt} &= -k_1x_A+k_2x_B\\ \frac{dx_B}{dt} &= k_1x_A-k_2x_B\end{aligned}$$
>
> (a) By taking derivatives show that $x_A$ satisfies a second order ODE.
>
> (b) Obtain the general solution for $x_A(t)$

I know how to do (a) and I found that

\begin{equation}
x_A''+(k_1+k_2)x_A'-2k_1k_2x_A=0
\end{equation}

Im just unsure about how to obtain the general solution to the ODE. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The usual technique is to assume a solution of the form $x_A=qe^{rt}$ and plug this in.  You get 
$$
x_A''+(k_1+k_2)x_A'-2k_1k_2x_A=0\\
qr^2e^{rt}+(k_1+k_2)qe^{rt}-2k_1k_2qe^{rt}=0\\
r^2+(k_1+k_2)-2k_1k_2=0
$$
which gives you a quadratic in $r$.  You get two solutions, $r_1$ and $r_2$, so $x_A=q_1e^{r_1t}+q_2e^{r_2t}$  You evaluate $q_1,q_2$ from the initial conditions.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
x_A'' &= -k_1x_A'+k_2x_B' \\
&= -k_1(-k_1 x_A + k_2 x_B) + k_2(k_1x_A-k_2x_B)\\
&= k_1^2x_A-k_1k_2x_B+k_2k_1x_A-k_2^2x_B \\
&= k_1(k_1+k_2)x_A-k_2(k_1+k_2)x_B \\
&= (k_1+k_2)(k_1x_A-k_2x_B) \\
&= (k_1+k_2)x_B'
\end{align}